# I did not understand the necessity of the "while " statement and the statement "if player:" in this code

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

I did not understand the necessity of the "while " statement and the statement "if player:" in this code -

```
def get_players_list():
    """() -> list of [str, int] list

    Prompt the player(s) to enter their names and return a list of player info
    as a two-item list with name and score, respectively.
    """

    players = []
    player = input('Enter player 1 name: ')
    while player.strip() or not players:  ##**#why is this needed?**
        player = player.strip() 

        if player in players:
            print("A player by that name is already playing.")

        if player: **# what is the function of this command#**
            players.append([player, 0])

        if players:
            print('Leave a blank player name to begin playing.')
        player = input('Enter player {num} name: '.format(num=len(players) + 1))

    return players
```

Comment: It repeats the loop until the user enters a valid player name and it's added to the `players` loop.

Comment: could you please tell me the function of if player: command?

Comment: In this context, `if player:` is equivalent to `if player != '':`

Comment: `player` is a string, and a non-empty string is truthy.

Comment: the while loop repeats until at least one name is in the list, and the user enters a blank name.   An empty string evaluates to False, and non-empty is True.  I think there is a logic bug because it will allow duplicate players even though there's a message.  and the last if player makes sure it doesn't create and entry with a blank name.

Comment: and what does players.append([player, 0]) do?

Answer (score 0):

Seems this is a dead block, since "players" is a list of list, but "player" is a string:

```
if player in players:
    print("A player by that name is already playing.")
```

So "if player in players:" condition will never happen.

Regarding 'if' block , it is required to add elements to 'players' list if your input is not blank. Checking the 'if' condition is important only if 'players' is empty, in other cases it is always True.
'while' makes you input at least 1 valid input.